# Set a datatype java.util.Date property of proxy Java Object in Cache by Gateway Java

Tags: java, intersystems-cache, intersystems, intersystems-ensemble

I'm implementing a solution that integrates a Caché application with a Java application by a Java Gateway. In the Java application I have a object what have a property of datatype "java.util.Date" and I have to set this in the Caché application. What datatype Caché I can using for this and how set this variable in Caché?

Code:

```
S data = ???
S obj = ##class(my.objectClass).%New(gateway) 
D obj.setDh(data)
```

The class `my.objectClass` is a proxy class and data type of parameter in `setDh()` is `java.sql.Date`.

When I can set the `data` variable?

Regards,

Lucas Boeing Scarduelli.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem with the following solution.

In Java application, on class `my.objectClass` I assign propert as `java.sql.Timestamp`, consequently the setDh() with same data type parameter.

In Caché application, when I have to assign value of this proxy class I do so:

```
S data = $ZDT($H,3)
S obj = ##class(my.objectClass).%New(gateway) 
D obj.setDh(data)
```

Why use `java.sql.Timestamp` rather then `java.sql.Date`?

Basically because in my case I need of date and time information, and the native parser of `java.sql.Date` only consider the date information. Already the `java.sql.Timestamp` native parser consider date and time information.

Answer (score 1):

As [Java Proxy Class Mapping](http://docs.intersystems.com/ens20102/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=BLJV_classes) points out, there's a mapping for `java.sql.Date` to Caché type `DATE`, you might be good adviced to use that. 
As `java.sql.Date` is a subclass of `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date` has a constructor taking a `java.util.Date` conversion on Java side should be quite simple.

Comment: Right, but as I set propert valeu on Caché side?

Comment: In this case my code is: `S obj = ##class(my.objectClass).%New(gateway)`
`D obj.setDh(data)`

Comment: No, it's Caché. I'm creating a proxy object Java into Caché. The object "my.objectClass" into Caché is a proxy class that reference a Java class into the mapped JAR connected by the Gateway.

Comment: Ok, but how I set my "data" variable in Caché?

Comment: Right, I edit the question. Your answers were very important so far, you could help me in this other question too?

Comment: Please add your code (and maybe the java-class you're trying to set values in) to your question as well.